# Import Bulk users from Azure Active Directory to sql database using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-active-directory

Import Bulk users from *Azure Active Directory* to SQL database using ASP.NET MVC.

If a new user added means, it should reflect in SQL database also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SCIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_for_Cross-domain_Identity_Management), an open standard for this scenario. This is taken from the microsoft docs that describes using SCIM with Azure AD

> As an application developer, you can use the System for Cross-Domain Identity Management (SCIM) user management API to enable automatic provisioning of users and groups between your application and Azure AD. This article describes how to build a SCIM endpoint and integrate with the Azure AD provisioning service. The SCIM specification provides a common user schema for provisioning. When used in conjunction with federation standards like SAML or OpenID Connect, SCIM gives administrators an end-to-end, standards-based solution for access management.

([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/use-scim-to-provision-users-and-groups))

Basically you have to implement some well defined endpoints in your MVC app and Azure AD will take care of the syncing (it will call those endpoints).In your implementation you can access your database to store the user data.

[Here](https://github.com/AzureAD/SCIMReferenceCode) is a reference implementation using an in memory datastore.